# ansible register with loops

Tags: loops, ansible

I want to create user and gather their info in local file but with loop register is now working as expected.

I thought it was an indentation problem but no luck.

My playbook

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: Clearing Local file 
      local_action: shell echo "Zone,docode,doname,testuser Output" > user.csv



- hosts: app
  tasks:

    - name: Creating user Testuser
      become: yes 
      user: 
        name: "{{ item }}" 
        state: present 
        shell: "/bin/bash"
        password: "$6$mysecretsalt$qyctTVhRMS1ZSnCuzQNAM8Y7V/yqSEnyRbal0IYXSqSEVKkXF8ZmXBZoRIaN/PvzE/msq8iOJO830OOCG89va/"  
        update_password: always 
        groups: santosh 

      shell: id "{{item}}"   
      ragister: userout  

      loop: 
        - newuser1
        - newuser2
        - newuser3

    - debug: 
        var=userout
```

which gives the following error when executed

```
ERROR! conflicting action statements: shell, user

The error appears to have been in '/home/santosh/ans-home/playbooks/Create_User_and_Gather_output.yml': line 12, column 7, but may
be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.

The offending line appears to be:


    - name: Creating user Testuser
      ^ here
```

Comment: Hi...WC to SO! kindly go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example on how to create a better OP in SO!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call several modules in one task, you need to separate each call in its own task, as reported by the error message.

I understand why you tried it: to take advantage of the same loop for several task. Unfortunately this is not possible. You could move your set of tasks to a separate file and include it in a loop if you really have to loop over a significant amount of tasks. This is not really required in your situation because:

- you only have two tasks
- you can compact writing of your loop by using a declared var for reuse
- and most essentially because you don't need your second task

In fact, the user module will return the uid of the user it created or that is existing in its result. You just have to register the result of calling the `user` module.

Just try the following for your second play:

```
- name: Resgister application users
  hosts: app

  vars:
    user_list:
      - newuser1
      - newuser2
      - newuser3

  tasks:
    - name: Create the users if they don't exist
      user:
        name: "{{ item }}" 
        state: present 
        shell: "/bin/bash"
        password: "$6$mysecretsalt$qyctTVhRMS1ZSnCuzQNAM8Y7V/yqSEnyRbal0IYXSqSEVKkXF8ZmXBZoRIaN/PvzE/msq8iOJO830OOCG89va/"  
        update_password: always 
        groups: santosh
      register: create_users
      loop: "{{ user_list }}"

    - name: Show ids of users
      debug:
        msg: "The uid of user {{ item.name }} is: {{ item.uid }}"
      loop: "{{ create_users.results }}"
```

And as a side note: for your first play, do yourself a favor and stop using the old `local_action` syntax in favor of `delegate_to: localhost` for a task. It is not even required in your case as your are already targeting your play to localhost only.

Comment: Thanks @Zeitounator it worked for me but i want to collect user name and ids in local file with local_action

Comment: Now that you have the solution to collect your data, you can do that very easily using the [`template` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/template_module.html) and [delegating](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_delegation.html#delegation) to localhost. This is an other subject than your initial question though.